# How to make plain text http2(h2c) load test using grafana k6

Tags: performance, performance-testing, load-testing, k6

I know k6 is able to promote to http2 if the server is supported. But there seems no means to generate h2c traffic which is used far and wide in internal network element communication. Anyone know how to do such test?

Answer (score 0):

No, h2c is currently not supported by k6. There's an open GitHub issue to track progress: https://github.com/grafana/k6/issues/970